# Prevent blank fields in PHP search forms

Tags: php, mysql

I have a HTML form pointing to a `PHP` script which searches my `MySQL` database. If users don't enter any values into the form I want to return an error message to them. I've tried the code below but what happens is that now, even if I have a value entered into a form field it returns the error message below.
Can you point out what is wrong, or even suggest an alternative if the commands below aren't the best.

```
if ($_POST['checkbox01'] == "on")
{
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM colour", $connection) or die("Cannot run     query");
    //Search for all records
}

elseif (!$_POST[''])
//Or else, if no fields are filled in...
{
    die('Please complete at least one search field');
    //Give an error message
}

else
... //Search the MySQL db using vaues entered into the form
```

(I've also tried...)

```
elseif(empty($_POST[''])) 
{
die('Please complete at least one search field');
}
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: where is the Textbox. please paste the Form code also.

Comment: Better to implement javascript :-) .Atleast it will save the round time needed for request and response

Answer (score 1):

I think the [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function is what you need here, and I would combine it with logic to check all your form input fields, e.g. (quick hacky example - though don't use die for a real solution):

```
vfield1 = "";
vfield2 = "";
vfield3 = "";

if (isset($_POST['field1'])) { vfield1 = $_POST['field1']; }
if (isset($_POST['field2'])) { vfield2 = $_POST['field2']; }
if (isset($_POST['field3'])) { vfield3 = $_POST['field3']; }

if (vfield1.vfield2.vfield3 == "") {
    die('Please complete at least one search field');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at [this](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/tutorials/building-real-time-form-validation-using-jquery/)?
It is a realtime validiation wich worked well for my form.

Answer (score 0):

On a side note it might help if you are checking against checkboxes to specify a value, ie:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="search_active" value="t" />
```

....then check it in PHP with

```
if ($_POST['search_active'] == "t") { // box checked } else { //box not checked }
```

Anyway, to check columns, I'd fill an array with mandatory columns, and then foreach over the POST array to check if the columns are all there.

...even better would be to use some sort of jQuery validation which means that you don't need to even reload the page :)

Here's some example code for filling an array with mandatory columns :)

```
$field_check = array("field1", "field2", "field3");
foreach ($field_check as $field) { 
   if (empty($_POST[$field])) { 
      die("Please enter a value into $field");
   }
}
// if we have got to here - continue with the search.
mysql_query(....);
```

Comment: np. Although you should not simply use `empty()`: http://codepad.viper-7.com/staVQJ

Comment: Well, it obviously depends on what sort of input he is expecting - but 0 would probably be invalid if it's supposed to be text or whatever :). It wasn't meant to be a full 100% solution, just a simple demonstration of better coding practice for checking multiple fields for "" or '' or similar useless data. :)

Comment: It will be text that will be entered into the form fields

Answer (score 0):

$_POST[''] won't do anything, $_POST is an array of the fields sent from the form. For example, if you have a simple login form (username/password), the $_POST array would look something like:

```
array('username' => 'value', 'password' => 'value');
```

If you want to check if all of your fields are empty, you're better off running a loop through the array. E.g.:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
   if($value == "") { die("Please enter a value into $key") }
}
```

Comment: Im not worried about them leaving some form fields empty, just so long as when they submit the form they have entered details into at least 1 of the fields, so they have at least 1 value to search the db against. Not every field must contain a value.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
<?php

echo '
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="search"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    // Check if NOT searchfield is emty
    if(!$_POST['search'] == "") {
        echo $_POST['search'];
    }

    else {
        echo 'You have to search for something!';
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Things like this should be easier to implement on the client side using some Javascript. jQuery has some very useful methods for this, for example:

```
$('#Your_Form input').blur(function()
{
    if( $(this).val().length == 0 ) {
        $('#warningDiv').addClass('warning');
    }
    else{
        $('#warningDiv').removeClassClass('warning');
    }
});
```

Whereas `#warningDiv` could be a div that is turned red when an input is empty. You could also implement similar behaviour in an inputs keypress/change event to periodically check for a value.

If you insist of doing this on the server-side, I'd suggest going with a different answer.

Comment: What if I disable javascript?

Comment: Naturally, the jQuery approach doesn't work if Javascript is disabled. That question is kind of redundant.